# Optimising "i = b ? (i | mask) : (i & ~mask)"

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, ternary-operator

I want to be able to set or clear (multiple) bits of a `uintX_t t`.

`i` is a runtime variable (`uintX_t`).
`b` is a runtime variable (`uintX_t`) which is constrained to be `0` or `1`.

`mask` is a compile-time constant.

Is there a better way than:

```
i = b ? (i | mask) : (i & ~mask)
```

I'm looking to avoid branching, if that's possible.  Target is ARM, if it matters.

Comment: `i = b` or `i == b`?

Comment: @HongOoi `i = (b ? (i | mask) : (i & ~mask))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another alternative: Always set bits to 0 (left part) and optionally set bits to 1 (right part).

```
i = (i & ~mask) | (mask * b);
```

Comment: This also follows from Guilherme's answer and using that or distributes over and

Comment: @harold Is your comment accidentally missing something? End of it seems weird.

Comment: No I just didn't format it clearly, I mean that OR distributes over AND

Answer (score 6):

Exploiting the fact that `-1u` is the value with all bits set:

```
i = (i & ~mask) | (mask & -b);
```

or

```
i ^= (i ^ -b) & mask;
```

The second approach reduces the number of operations and code size. The first approach may still be faster on a superscalar architecture because some operations can be executed in parallel.

Comment: `-b` and `-1u` isn't the same thing though. If `b` is a small integer type of any signedness, you end up with a negative number temporarily. Unlike `-1u` which is always a positive number. It won't be a problem in this specific case, but would have been disastrous in code like `(mask & -b) << n`.

Comment: @Lundin Right, there is actually a problem with the code in my answer if `b` is narrower than `int` and the platform doesn't use two's complement. In this case, an additional cast `-(unsigned)b` is needed.

Answer (score 5):

The idea here is to replace the branch by a multiplication, where we can zero each side depending on the value of b:

```
i = (i | (mask * b)) & (~mask | (mask * b));
```

Comment: I tested in Java, if you want, i can post the test code in java that shows that it really works

Comment: Now the question is: what is worse in terms of performance loss, branching or multiplying ?

Comment: In my tests, i used i = 101 (binary), mask = 110 (binary)

Comment: You can easily find that adding both codes and running them 1 million times each, and measuring the time.

Comment: You can trivially rewrite the multiplication as a negation and a bitwise AND, in case you have slow multiplications (typically this is worth rewriting that way)

Answer (score 1):

The most readable way is to do this in several steps - doing so won't affect performance but improve readability.

As is always the case with bit-wise operators, you must be careful with implicit type promotions. For example, careless use of `~` tends to create implicit promotion bugs. (The `?:` operator also silently promotes the result by balancing the 2nd and 3rd operands with each other.)

Readable, portable, safe code:

```
uintx_t i = ... ;
uintx_t b = ... ;  // 1 or 0

i &= (uintx_t)~mask;   // always clear the bit
i |= mask * b;         // if b is 1, set the bit, otherwise OR with 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this readable approach.  If `i` is PORTA on an AVR, would this cause a GPIO glitch?  Or are the two statements merged into one during compilation?  I *expect* that PORTA is marked volatile to stop that happening.

Comment: @chrisdew It would cause the GPIO to go low for a couple of clock ticks. The compiler is not allowed to optimize the code since `PORTA` would be a volatile register. On some hardwares, GPIO ports may need a few clock ticks to stabilize though.